# XML DOMDocument method selectSingleSpace failing on carriage returns in tags

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm trying to select a node in an xml file which contains a known string, but also contains a potentially variable number of whitespace characters such as spaces and carriage returns.  Is there a way to.  When I try a line like:

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")

Set objNode = objXML.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//Main/Subgroup/MyTag[Label='SomeText']")
```

It works with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?> 
  <Main>
    <Subgroup>
      <MyTag>
        <Label>SomeText</Label>
      </MyTag>
    </Subgroup>
  </Main>
```

But it returns null with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?> 
  <Main>
    <Subgroup>
      <MyTag>
        <Label>
          SomeText
        </Label>
      </MyTag>
    </Subgroup>
  </Main>
```

Is there a way to format that Label text, with wildcard characters or something similar, or is that a flag to have it ignore whitespace?  I found this preserveWhiteSpace member variable for objXML, but setting it to false didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using XPath, you can use the `contains(node, selectiontext)` function, ie

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")
objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objXML.load "file.xml"
Set objNode = objXML.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//Main/Subgroup/MyTag[contains(Label, 'SomeText')]")
```

although this will also match any string that incorporates 'SomeText'. Another approach would be to use `normalize-space(node)`:

```
Set objNode = objXML.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//Main/Subgroup/MyTag[normalize-space(Label) = 'SomeText']")
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just the simple, elegant solution I was looking for.